# How can I sort date array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please see my following code snippet

**Input**
list_x = ["11/1/2100", "5/12/1999", "19/1/2003", "11/9/2001"]

### **Output**

`['5/12/1999', '11/9/2001', '19/1/2003', '11/1/2100']`

Comment: @polarise It's also a rather common question with numerous existing answers.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm responding to the comment that the question is not clear. Your response addresses a separate issue.

Comment: @polarise Oh, ok. I agree that it probably doesn't deserve a downvote, OTOH, the OP probably should have done a little more research first, both in the Python docs and for existing questions here.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your day/month format to day in year format and then compare each element in the list based on the year then the day